# Unchecked Cast Warning: interface as return value, stored in Class implementing said interface

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

My situation is, I have a function

`public static MyInterface doSomething() {...}`

and a Class

`MyList<O extends MyObject> extends MyListObject<O> implements MyInterface`

and:

- `MyObjectA` extends `MyObject`
- `MyListObject` just implements the interfaces `Collection<O>` and `List<O>`

My Problem now is, that following code

`MyList<MyObjectA> var = (MyList<MyObjectA>)doSomething();`

produces a

> `Type safety: Unchecked cast from MyInterface to MyList<MyObjectA>`

warning.
Why is that so? I mean `doOperation()` returns a `MyInterface` type and `MyList` implements said interface...

I hope my code example explains the complete relation between all classes and interfaces and that I haven't missed anything.

Comment: While `doOperation()` returns a `MyInterface`, you can't be sure it returns a `MyList`. You programmed it as if it's a fact, the compiler is telling you that it's an unsafe cast. It will fail at runtime if you return anything else. It's a bad bad construct, and somewhat surprising design choice from your part.

Comment: `MyInterface` is not necessarily a `MyList`.

Comment: Because you could have multiple classes that implement `MyInterface`. The method you're calling just returns `MyInterface` as well, so there's no guarantee that you can actually cast the result to `MyList<MyObjectA>`

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful explanations. Now I actually understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the type in a cast may not contain `<…>`, unless it is `<?>`.  (There are exceptions to this rule, but they’re corner cases, and not relevant here.)

Generics are a compile-time type checking mechanism.  At runtime, there does not exist a `MyList<MyObjectA>` class, due to type erasure.  There is only a single `MyList` class.

This means the compiler can only generate this code:

```
(MyList<?>) doSomething();
```

Attempting to force the compiler to assume that the result has a specific generic type is *unsafe,* because the code which will do the cast cannot check for that.  Thus, your cast is an unchecked cast.

The *safe* way to do this is to perform non-generic casts:

```
MyList<MyObjectA> var = new MyList<>();
MyList<?> list = (MyList<?>) doSomething();
for (Object element : list) {
    var.add((MyObjectA) element);
}
```

*Caution:* `var` is now a reserved keyword in Java.  You should avoid using it as a variable name.

Comment: I chose 'var' because I couldn't think of any variable name while typing. Your answer helped me resolve the issue, thank you very much!

Comment: @Chayze If you feel this answer adequately addresses your question, feel free to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretending `MyInterface` was a `MyList<>` but I am pretty sure it is not–despite you not showing the actual definition of `MyInterface`.

Metaphorically spoken you're trying to treat every tool (`MyInterface`) as a hammer (`MyList<>`).

If you're sure that `doSomething()` always returns a `MyList`, you can mark the method containing the cast with a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation. But then, why would you declare `doSomething()` as returning the more general `MyInterface` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Flying {
   void fly();
}

class Bird extends Animal implements Flying {
    ...
}

List<Flying> listFlying();

List<Flying> list = listFlying();
```

If you indeed only use methods of the interface, you can use:

```
list.forEach(flying -> flying.fly());
```

Otherwise safety requires some shoveling:

```
List<Bird> birds = list.stream() // Or listFlying().stream()
    .filter(Bird.class::isInstance)
    .map(Bird.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```